# How does finder show a pc computer name but I can't ping it?

Tags: macos, network

I have a MBP running 10.6.  This is my first mac.

In finder, it sees the windows 7 machines and windows home server just find.  I can click on those computers and see their shares.  If I open up terminal and try to ping the computer name, it doesn't resolve.  I have had to add the computers to the host file.  I don't understand why finder appears to associate the name with the correct server from the terminal doesn't.  Can somebody explain it or explain how I can get the same behavior from terminal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a machine is found via Bonjour/multicast DNS, you may need to add a `.local` suffix to use the hostname in Terminal.  If it was found via NetBIOS (either broadcast or WINS), you may need to use `nmblookup` to get an IP address:

```
rushlight:10120 Z$ nmblookup mress
querying mress on 10.0.204.255
10.0.204.14 mress<00>
10.0.204.14 mress<00>
```

Answer (score 0):

ping on Mac OS X uses basic host lookup via DNS or Bonjour, but your Windows machines are (most likely) being advertised on your network by NetBIOS which ping doesn't consult.

Answer (score 0):

If the ping can't resolve the host, then it's a DNS issue; your computer doesn't have a way to translate the computer name into an IP address.

When Finder looks for computers to share files with, it probably sends a packet to what's called a "multicast" address, which just means it goes to all devices on the network/subnet.  It'll say something to the effect of "Hey, do you want to share files?"  Any computers with file sharing enabled will respond.  This can also be accomplished through [Bonjour](http://developer.apple.com/networking/bonjour/faq.html).

As far as how to get Terminal to do the same thing, I don't think you can link it with Finder's list of file-sharing partners.  When given a computer name, ping will need an IP to send its request to, and that has to come from either DNS or your hosts file.